# I not understand how use es6 modules with typescript 2

Tags: typescript

Please, help me, i not understand how use es6 modules in TS. 
For example:

**I trying import ext.class to class1.ts.**

```
class1.ts
import ExtClass from "./ext.class";
class Class1 {
    constructor(){
        console.log(new ExtClass().title)
        console.log("Work")
    }
}
new Class1();
```

**Its exporting class**

```
ext.class.ts
class ExtClass {
    public title: string = "ExtClass work";
}
export default ExtClass

package.json
{
  "name": "ts_def",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2"
  }
}
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

In result i recieve **Unexpected token import** in CLI and browser. Please, say me, whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Now you are outputing es6 code from typescript. Right now this is not useful unless you plan to transpile that further to ES5 code.

Usually the way modules are used is by transpiling the code to ES5 and having tsc transpile the ES6 modules to an ES5 module definition, for example systemjs modules, and at runtime load them using a module loader, like SystemJS.